# biblatex \cite as superscript brackets

Tags: biblatex, brackets, superscripts

I have a question according to my citation and the bibliography:

**How did it got printed in the text is**:
A[18] instead of A^[18]  also A[18][20][19] results not in A^[18-20]

**with**

[18] J. Hua, X. Li, Y.-S. Li, L. Xu, Y.-X. Li, Journal of Applied Polymer Science
2007, 104, 3517–3522.

[19] Z. M. Hudson, D. J. Lunn, M. A. Winnik, I. Manners, Nature communications
2014, 5, 3372.

[20] K. Ishihara, M. Mu, T. Konno, Y. Inoue, K. Fukazawa, Journal of biomaterials
science. Polymer edition 2017, 28, 884–899.

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm} %do I need that
\documentclass[pagesize=pdftex, paper=a4, parskip, fontsize=12pt, toc=bibnumbered, captions=tableheading, captions=nooneline, BCOR=5mm, DIV=calc, headsepline]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel} 
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=chem-angew,citestyle=numeric-comp,sortcites= true]{biblatex} 

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{top=2.5cm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[percent]{overpic}
\usepackage{wrapfig} 
\usepackage{overpic}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{upgreek} 
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{textgreek}
 \chemsetup{greek=textgreek}
 \chemsetup{modules=all} \chemsetup[acid-base]{p-style=slanted}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{siunitx}
 \sisetup{separate-uncertainty-units=repeat,use-xspace=true, sticky-per=true, range-units=single, range-phrase={\,--\,}, list-units=single, per-mode=power-positive-first, multi-part-units=single, product-units=single}
 \DeclareSIUnit{\angstrom}{\textup{\AA}}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
 \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.2} 
\usepackage{multicol} 
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{xspace} \usepackage{setspace} \onehalfspacing
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage} 



\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
\usepackage{chemstyle}
  

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks}
\addbibresource{Latex_phD_Literature.bib}


\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}

\begin{center}

Questions: How to use latex correctly? 
\end{center}

\end{titlepage}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage 
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
I use planty of usepackages and it might be a few to old once. But I lost the track now.

Now to my question:
I try to use citation like that \cite{Hua.2007} and \cite{Hudson.2014} and \cite{Ishihara.2017} as supercite for all references in brackets. 
How do I do that? Also if I use multiply references their is no numeric-comp function in the text. 
\printbibliography %should be printed as followed with chem=angew
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

`biblatex` has a `\supercite` command, but that does not come with brackets, so we have to slightly redefine it.

We also set `\autocite` to issue `\supercite` for us.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel} 
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=chem-angew,
  citestyle=numeric-comp,
  sortcites=true,
  autocite=superscript,
]{biblatex} 

\newcommand*{\mkbibbracketsuperscript}[1]{%
  \mkbibsuperscript{%
    \mkbibbrackets{#1}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\supercite}[\mkbibbracketsuperscript]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \let\multicitedelim=\supercitedelim
   \let\multicitesubentrydelim=\supercitesubentrydelim
   \let\multiciterangedelim=\superciterangedelim
   \let\multicitesubentryrangedelim=\supercitesubentryrangedelim
   \iffieldundef{prenote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
   \iffieldundef{postnote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
Lorem\autocite{sigfridsson}
ipsum\autocite{worman}
dolor\autocite{nussbaum}
sit\autocite{sigfridsson,worman,nussbaum}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: "Lorem^[2] ipsum^[3] dolor^[1] sit^[1–3]" with citations in superscript]

Comment: thanks for your fast answer, does it mean than that I can not use \cite anymore and I have to reorganize everything again? With Texmaker you have the fast ref with \cite instead of using \autocite. And thanks I did not know that I have to them together in one brackets. makes it all a bit more tipping as I am using a assistent program

Comment: Say `\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}` instead of `\DeclareCiteCommand{\supercite}` above,

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. By the way do you maybe know how to make the order of citation over the hole "book"? I have am Abstract bevor my tables and then a clearpage to start the paragraph with aracbic numbers. So the citation in the abstract start counting with 10 .

Comment: @Katrin That would be a new question, I think. Normally, I'd expect the sorting to also take into account the abstract and ignore the tables of contents etc.